# How to enable Huawei Health app options for iOS that exist for Android?

Tags: ios, android, health.app

I bought a [Huawei Band 3 Pro](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/wearables/band3-pro/) some months back, and while using it with my Android phone, all the things I needed were working (using the Android [Huawei Health](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.huawei.health) app).

But lately, I switched to an iPhone 11 pro, and thus using the iOS version of that app. And it seems that the iOS app lacks in various aspects. But maybe I just didn't find the right place to configure it correctly.

What is missing for me:

- With Android, I could enable "notifications" that go to the band *per* source. Meaning: I would first enable notifications in general, and *then* I could select "I want calendar events and phone calls, but I don't want facebook or WhatsApp". With iOS: I only found "notifications" that can be enabled. And now I get calendar events, phone calls, facebook, whatsapp ... just a lot of things I really don't want to be notified about. **Question**: is there a way to configure individual sources for notifications?
- Beyond that, the band knows various forms of exercises. Like indoor cycling. Which ... the Huawei health app doesn't show me at all. With Android, I could see past trainings, for **all** the exercises that the band offers. With iOS, there is only steps, heartbeat, sleep ... and 3 outdoor (GPS based) activities. **Question**: is there a way to access these "missing" activities, like training data for indoor cycling?

Comment: Have you asked the support for the Huawei Health iOS app?  https://apps.apple.com/us/app/huawei-health/id1325481372

Comment: @TomGewecke I did fill out a form and had something mailed to "somewhere" at Huawei some time back. No response. Also note: that link you gave me, in the bottom it says: "App support". When I click that, I end up with "Invalid URL
The requested URL "[no URL]", is invalid." ... but yes, I am following up on that approach. I merely asked here to A) be surprised by maybe a good answer coming in and B) to openly document this deficiency, so that future readers find some information about the problem (my own research didn't show up *anything* on this specific issue).

Comment: You might want to file a review for that app regarding its shortcomings.

Comment: @TomGewecke Did so yesterday, on the "German" app store. Going to rework my initial review on amazon as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say if I just overlooked that, or if a newer version of the health app improved things: I can now see the my indoor cycling activities, too. They show up in the overview of outdoor cycling. Unfortunately, that overview only sums up distances, so the time spent on the indoor device don't count.  But at least, they all show up.

<s>I also noticed that the user guide for another new huawei device, the Gt2 watch, explicitly mentions that certain features (such as installing watch faces from the huawei servers) only works with the android app.</s>

But I can confirm that it is straight forward to switch the device between different phones, as I used my old android phone to install other watch faces, before connecting it with my iPhone.

**EDIT/Update**: things are further improving for iOS users!

In 2021, the only thing feature that I see on Android, but not on iOS: the ability to manage tracks manually (as in: modifying "recorded" trainings, or adding a training completely after the fact).